# About Virtuoso Yago in Java

Tags: sparql, semantics, virtuoso

I use the code below for get `hasLongitude` and `hasLatitude` from `yago` with java use virtuoso but I don't receive anything :(( Is there any problem in this code??

```
VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph ("jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba"); 
        Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("PREFIX yago: <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/> " + 
             "SELECT DISTINCT ?long ?lat " + 
             " FROM <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource> " + 
             " WHERE {" + 
             " yago:London yago:hasLatitude ?long. " + 
             " yago:London yago:hasLongitude ?lat. " + 
             " }"); 
        VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set); 
        ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
        while (results.hasNext()) { 
             QuerySolution rs = results.nextSolution(); 
             RDFNode s = rs.get("long"); 
             RDFNode p = rs.get("lat"); 
             System.out.println(" { " + s + " " + p + " . }"); }
```

Comment: From AKSW (not enough rep to comment) : Please give some details *Which data have you loaded? Is the namespace correct? Does it work on another endpoint?*

Comment: I import : 
- yagoGeonamesClasses
- yagoGeonamesClassIds
- yagoGeonamesData
- yagoGeonamesEntityIds
- yagoGeonamesGlosses
- yagoGeonamesOnlyData
--When i try this query in lSPARQL Execution on localhost,i recieve a list of : long and lat